# objcopy generate huge binary file (265M)

Tags: object, linker, binary, objcopy

When trying to generate a binary file removing two text sections I end up with a huge binary file of 265M.

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -v -O binary --remove-section=.text_F3 --remove-section=.text_F4 file.axf out_file.bin
```

Has anybody has a clue why this would happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, one of the sections I was trying to remove was "allocable" and that was the whole issue objcopy doesn't deal well with "allocable" sections.